# Compiler switch or preprocessor switch?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Switching code using the preprocessor is pretty common:

```
#define MY_SWITCH (1)
#if MY_SWITCH
   cout << "on" << Test(1);
#else
   cout << "off" << Test(2);
#endif
```

However if the code outside this snippet changes (e.g. if the Test() function is renamed) it could happen that the disabled line would remain outdated since it is not compiled.

I would like to do this using a different kind of switch to let the code being compiled on every build so I can find outdated lines immediately. E.g. like this:

```
static const bool mySwitch = true;
if (mySwitch)
{
   cout << "on" << Test(1);
}
else
{
   cout << "off" << Test(2);
}
```

However I need to prevent this method to consumes additional ressources. Is there any guaranty (or a reliable assumption) that modern C++ compilers will remove the inactive branch (e.g. using optimization)?

Comment: Any good optimizing compiler should remove the dead branch.

Comment: Is there a guarantee? No, that would imply that the standard mandates it. Will most compilers remove unused branches during optimization? Yes.

Comment: Can't you just test both builds for the preprocessor solution?

Comment: Yes, I probably could to this using differently configured projects/targets... but if the compiler based alternative would work fine I could avoid that effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have *guarantee* about compiler optimization. (If you want proven optimizations for C, look into  [compcert](http://compcert.inria.fr/)).

However, most compilers would optimize in that case, and some might even warn about dead code. Try with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) with optimizations enabled (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2`).

Also, I believe that most compilers won't consume resources at execution time of the generated optimized code, but they will consume resources at compilation time.

Perhaps using `constexpr` might help some compilers to optimize better.

Also, look at the produced assembly code (e.g. with `g++ -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`) or at the intermediate dumps of the compiler (e.g. `g++ -O2 -fdump-tree-all` which gives *hundreds* of dump files). If using GCC, you might customize it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to e.g. add additional compile-time checks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem just a few weeks ago — disabling a problematic diagnostic feature in my codebase revealed that the alternative code had some newish bugs in it that prevented compilation. However, I wouldn't go down the route you propose.

You're sacrificing the benefit of using macros in the first place and not necessarily gaining anything. I expect my compiler to optimise the dead branch away *but* you can't rely on it *and* I feel that the macro approach makes it a lot more obvious that there are two distinct "configurations" of your program and only one can ever be used from within a particular build.

I would let your continuous integration system (or whatever is driving automated build tests) cycle through the various combinations of build configuration (provide macros using `-D` on the commandline, possibly from within your Makefile or other build script, rather than hardcoding them in the source) and *test them all*.

Comment: +1 I like this continuous integration system for cycling through various build configuration, it helps in working with "ancestor"/legacy codes as well.

Comment: @P0W: Yep exactly. I mean, we automate builds of both debug and release configurations already, right? So why not this too =)

Comment: Currently we do not use an automated build system. Anyway, adding alternative targets would be a solution too.